# Vagrant Running Services between host and guest

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, portforwarding

I am working in a software where I am running a couple of specific web service in the host machine and I want to access them from the guest machine. These are the configuration of my services.

guest IP : 192.168.33.10

host IP : 192.168.1.100

---

The services on the host runs on port `10001`, `7000`. When I try to connect to the service on port `10001` everything works fine. But I cannot connect to the service in port `7000`.

- I connect to the service on port 10001 in the host in the following
  URL http://192.168.1.100:10001
- I connect to the service on port 10001 in the host in the following
  URL http://192.168.1.100:7000

  I get the message `Failed to connect to 192.168.33.1 port 7000: Connection refused`.

Can anyone tell me the reason and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the second service. Reconfigure the first onto 7000 port to see if it still works. If not, try a different port. If so you can rule out firewall/vagrant etc.

If it turns out to be a service specific issue, which IP address does the second service bind to? localhost/127.0.0.1/192.168.1.100? The service might never be accessible via the public IP 192.168.1.100.